# How to center images that are in the cycle design and colorbox plugin to the center of the webpage

Tags: html, css, colorbox, jquery-cycle

How do I center the whole box to the center of my webpage. I have tried everything to get it to work.

Comment: here is the mark up if it is not showing above

Comment: You really need to include some more information here before anyone can help.

Comment: Its difficult to offer a good solution without seeing an example or more code, but here is an article with several good centering techniques - http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

add a **margin: 0 auto;** style to your div, will place it in the top center, then you can add a % to pad it from the top if needed... otherwise use the solution @Talkingrock had